# Why bother to initialize a reduction variable outside the parallel construct?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, directive, clause

I am learning how to port my Fortran code to OpenMP. When I read an online tutorial (see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.nic.uoregon.edu/iwomp2005/iwomp2005_tutorial_openmp_rvdp.pdf&ei=ihVGU_aHEcemygGpiIG4DQ&usg=AFQjCNEcJGRCDDbOaRNa_0VS-c8bcytSeQ&sig2=V7Zv1sj_T-Ubu3NYBC5qhw&bvm=bv.64507335,d.aWc)) I came across one question.

At first, I knew from page 28 that the value of a reduction variable is undefined from the moment the first thread reaches the clause till the operation has completed.

To my understanding, the statement implies that it doesn't matter whether I initialize the reduction variable before the program hits the parallel construct, because it is not defined until the complete of the operation. However, the sample code on page 27 of the same tutorial initializes the reduction variable before the parallel construct.

Could anyone please let me know which treatment is correct? Thanks.

Lee

```
sum = 0.0
!$omp parallel default(none) shared(n,x) private(i)
do i = 1, n
   sum = sum + x(i)
end do
!$omp end do
!$omp end parallel
print*, sum
```

Comment: Note that while you can legitimately call `sum` a reduction variable in your code it is not an OpenMP reduction variable.  There is no `reduction` clause on the `parallel` directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After fixing your code:

```
integer,parameter :: n = 10000
real :: x(n)

x = 1

sum = 0
!$omp parallel do default(none) shared(x) private(i) reduction(+:sum)
do i = 1, n
   sum = sum + x(i)
end do
!$omp end parallel do
print*, sum 
end
```

Notice, that the value to which you initialize `sum` matters! If you change it you get a different result. It is quite obvious you have to initialize it properly and even the OpenMP version is ill-defined without proper initialization.

Yes, the value of sum is not defined until completing the loop, but that doesn't mean it can be undefined *before* the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One more question. In OpenMP manual it says that the initialization that goes with the operator "+" is zero. If it is the case, why do we need to worry about the initial value assigned to sum before hitting the parallel region?

Comment: A local copy of each list varia
ble is made and initialized
depending on the “op” (e.g. 0 for “+”).
–
Compiler finds standard redu
ction expressions containing
“op” and uses them to update the local copy.
–
**Local copies are reduced
into a single value and
combined with the original global value.**

Comment: So yes, the original initial value *does* matter.

Answer (score 4):

For one thing, one of the nice features of OpenMP is that if you compile the program without enabling OpenMP, the program can/(should!) be a valid serial program as well. The serial version of your example would be ill-defined without initializing "sum" before the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You did remind me of some basic concept when inspecting whether anything goes wrong during the transition from serial to parallel program. One more question. In OpenMP maunal it says that the initialization that goes with the operator "+" is zero. If it is applicable to my original question, then why bother to initialize the variable? Is the manual wrong?

Comment: @isyegatech: to reitetate my answer, if you compile without enabling openmp it doesn't matter what the openmp manual says, you should check your fortran manual.

Comment: ...and, as Vladimir F says, there's a difference between the global variable sum and the local variables for each thread.